# is there anyway that i can move to some frame in actionscript based on a random number from a dice?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

here's the thing, i am actually new to actionscript and currently developing a a game in flash. the game is snakes and ladders. i have problems with regards to how to move the player avatar  to the boxes of the game board. here's what i did. i made 100 frames, and with each frame is where the position of the avatar. (for example, frame 2 shows that the avatar is in box 2, etc).only thing is how do i make the frame move depending on a random number given by the dice.?

for example if i was originally in frame 2, and the dice gave a random number of 5, how do i get to frame 7? like playing the frames 3 - 6 and stopping at frame 7?

Answer (score 0):

To move to a specified frame, invoke `gotoAndStop()` with a frame number as parameter. Of course, it can be calculated, and you can refer to movieclip's current frame via `currentFrame` property.

[The manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndStop%28%29)

Comment: if i did that, the avatar directly goes to that specified frame, is there any way that it goes to the preceeding frames first, before it goes to its destination?

Comment: First, what if you'd decide your character to move some frames backwards - what should it do? Yes, you can employ such a function, but it's not a single call.

Comment: could you please show me how? im not actually good at this language yet(: